# How to add a second drop down list to Action Bar in Android Honeycomb?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I've been playing with Honeycomb for the last week and had a hard time to find something about more than one drop-down list in Action Bar.
I've used [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) tutorial and successfully added one drop-down list to it. But I don't know how to add another one. Please tell me if you know how to do it.
Thanks.

P.S. also one little this how can I change the position of elements in Action Bar(this is off topic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do that yourself. Instead of `setNavigationMode()`, use [`setCustomView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29).

> P.S. also one little this how can I change the position of elements in Action Bar(this is off topic)?

Generally, you can't. You control the order (e.g., toolbar buttons via the order they are in your options menu XML). That's pretty much it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It feels like I can place things where I want in my 'CustomView'. Hopefully I'll try to play with it this evening. Any articles about it? I've checked [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: @Alex Bush: I haven't run into anything that uses the custom view yet, and I have not yet tried it myself, for that spot in the action bar. If you want your `Spinner` more to be on the right, then you could use `android:actionView` in your options menu XML. I have a sample of that here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: Yep, it worked! I got a custom view in my Action Bar and I use couple of PopupMenus and Spinners in there. Thanks!

Comment: android:actionLayout just what i needed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about Honeycomb but I was able to add two drop down lists to my action bar in JellyBean without using a custom view.

res/menu/main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_status_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );

    MenuItem mainMenuSpinner = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_main_spinner);
    setupMainMenuSpinner( mainMenuSpinner );

    MenuItem statusSpinner = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_status_spinner );
    setupStatusSpinner( statusSpinner );

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setupMainMenuSpinner(MenuItem item) {
    View view = item.getActionView();
    if (view instanceof Spinner) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;
        spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.main_menu_options,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item));
    }
}

private void setupStatusSpinner(MenuItem item) {
    View view = item.getActionView();
    if (view instanceof Spinner) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;
        spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.status,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item));
    }
}
```